# Lambda function starts, not executed, and timeout is reached

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function triggered by API Gateway. I trigger it, and I see in the logs that it's starting but nothing happens, it's stuck and the timeout is reached. The very first line of the actual function is a `console.log` that is not printed at all.

This is the log of the lambda:

```
2021-10-20T13:27:50.740+03:00   START RequestId: effb5220-abd0-492a-a355-e17cba47b491 Version: $LATEST

2021-10-20T13:29:22.746+03:00   END RequestId: effb5220-abd0-492a-a355-e17cba47b491

2021-10-20T13:29:22.746+03:00   REPORT RequestId: effb5220-abd0-492a-a355-e17cba47b491 Duration: 92004.98 ms Billed Duration: 90000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB

2021-10-20T13:29:22.746+03:00   2021-10-20T10:29:22.746Z effb5220-abd0-492a-a355-e17cba47b491 Task timed out after 92.00 seconds
```

I don't know where else to debug this issue....

If it matters, the lambda function is in typescript using the CDK.

Comment: You have allocated and used 128MB, looks like you need more memory, try 1GB or more and see if that works.

Comment: @luk2302 you're right... silly me for missing that...